# Setup web service using Amazon AWS and tomcat

Tags: java, android, rest, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I am pretty new to Amazon AWS technologies, and I have been going through all their documentation. My goal is to create a new web service for a use case (preferably REST) using Tomcat.

I want to use this service in multiple clients like Android, Iphone, Tablet, Web etc. 
Some of the examples I want to support are like - 
GET http://myservice.com/user/{userid} 
PUT http://myservice.com/user/{user-data}

Does AWS or any other cloud service providers provide anything out of the box for deploying such services with minimal code changes?

Comment: Can you define what do you mean by minimal code changes a little bit more? Is your service going to run on a single server or are you more worried about the different platforms that your clients going to use?

Answer (score 1):

With AWS, you create a virtual server, customize it, and then use it. When you create a server, you pick your operating system and the size of the server you need. Once it is running, you can login and customize it.

For example, you might start a linux server using the Amazon Linux AMI (amazon machine image). You can use yum to install tomcat. You can drop your war file into the tomcat webapps directory.

Set up access in the security group (firewall) to allow your clients to access the relevant port(s).

Bottom line is that the process is basically the same as if you are doing this on a new server of your own.